# How can I switch between 2 groups of handlers in netty

Tags: java, netty

I am trying to write a client server application that communicate using Message Objects(Message Class is defined in my application). there is a scenario in which i want to transfer file between them. First I must send a message to client to notify it about specific file information and after that the file itself is going to be written to channel.
The problem is how can I handle this scenario in client?
Is it a good solution to remove Message handler after receiving message and replace it with a byte array handler?
what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can just modify the pipeline on the fly. We do something similar in our portunification example[1].

[1] https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.0/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/portunification/PortUnificationServerHandler.java

Comment: Does the order in which you `remove` and `addLast` (say you only added one handler) matter? Why do you always call `remove` last in that example?